# How to access to my shape parameters in the main activity?

Tags: android, view

i wrote this code in my custom view class
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
Paint p1 = new Paint();
p1.setStyle(Style.FILL);
p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
p1.setAntiAlias(true);

RectF rect1 = new RectF(canvas.getWidth()/2,500, canvas.getWidth() ,canvas.getHeight() );
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect1, 4, 4, p1);
super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

and i want to access to the `rect1` parameters in my activity so i can change them dynamically, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add public getter and setter functions to your view class that retrieve or modify the parameters of the rect1 member, then call these functions from your activity class.

Comment: i tried but when i do public float getBottom for example, he refuses the float return i didn't knew what to put in there.

Comment: public float getBottom (){
return rect1.bottom;} the float is always underlined with red

Comment: You should define your rect1 top level in the class (i.e, before the onDraw method). This way it will be in scope for the whole class, and will be accessible in the getters and setters

Comment: i did that, still the same thing, he got pb with the float